# Xlnt library. Is there a way to store excel cell color information in rgb format?

Tags: c++, excel, colors, libraries, fill

I can't find any function which store cell color data in rgb format. I just simply want to get color from one cell and freely fill another cell with this color.

To fill cell I use this function,but can't find a way to store the color.
`cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(xlnt::rgb_color(242, 34, 15)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer lies in just using `cell.fill().pattern_fill().foreground().rgb()`. That's the easiest way to retrieve the color. However, I also created the implementation you described just as an example.

```
//This is what you asked for
xlnt::rgb_color get_cell_color(const xlnt::cell &cell) {
    if (cell.fill().type() == xlnt::fill_type::pattern) {
        xlnt::pattern_fill pattern = cell.fill().pattern_fill();
        if (pattern.foreground().type() == xlnt::color_type::rgb) {
            return pattern.foreground().rgb();
        }
    }
    return xlnt::rgb_color(0, 0, 0); // Default to black if no color is found
}

//I took the function you used to fill, and I made it fit in a little bit better 
void color_fill_cell(xlnt::cell &cell, const xlnt::rgb_color &rgb) {
    cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(rgb));
}
```

Now that we have those functions, we can implement them pretty easily:

```
xlnt::worksheet ws = ; // Just plop your worksheet here

xlnt::cell source_cell = ws.cell("A1"); //Obv A1 is a placeholder
xlnt::rgb_color rgb = get_cell_color(source_cell);

xlnt::cell target_cell = ws.cell("B1"); //placeholder again
color_fill_cell(target_cell, rgb);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful response, but I have encountered the following problem. e.g. `cell.has_fill()` i got error class xlnt::cell has no member "has fill"  Is this due to the lack of including the necessary header files?

Comment: @matnow My bad– I have fixed the issue. I had been looking at old (bad) code of mine from the past, and copied without thinking– `has_fill` is not, and never has been a thing, for the record. The correct way to ensure the safety of the function is via `if (cell.fill().type() == xlnt::fill_type::pattern)`. I have integrated it into the answer.

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply. However, there is probably one more thing that does not work as it should. I mean this piece of code: 

`if (pattern.foreground().type() == xlnt::color_type::rgb) { return pattern.foreground().rgb(); }`


`set()` C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list object type is: xlnt::optional<xlnt::color>

`rgb()` class has no member

thank you again for your help

Comment: Never mind, I already figured it out myself. I should be `pattern.foreground().get().type()` and `pattern.foreground().get().rgb()`.